# Clarification on what it means to apply parallelism to a program that counts occurrences of a target word

Tags: java, multithreading

This is for school. I'm writing a java program that counts the number of times a certain word occurs in a file, but it needs to use multi-threading to accomplish the task. I'm unsure what that quite means though: does parallelism mean that I get the file's total word count, make two threads and then give each one a different half of the file to process?

Answer (score 1):

> does parallelism mean that I get the file's total word count

This is not what the "parallelism" means. The "parallelism" means that you do the task parallelized, i.e. multiple activities solve one task.

> make two threads and then give each one a different half of the file to process

Yes. You split up the problem into smaller pieces, i.e. you seperate the file into abstract chunks and assign a thread to count the occurences of a given word to each.

After the parallelized counting you combine the results.